# Pygame quick pixel reading

Tags: python, algorithm, image, image-processing, pygame

Alright, hopefully someone can help me with this because I'm at a loss here.

I'm working on a game in python that uses the camera as the main controller. To play the game, you move a simple light around, and that controls the game.

So far, I've managed to get the camera image to a surface, and display it on the screen. But when it comes to finding the light, the program is slowed to a crawl.

My first attempt used the surface.get_at(x,y) function (this is not the actual code, this is an example):

```
maxL = 0
point = (0,0)
mysurface = get_cameraImg()
for i in range(mysurface.get_width()):
    for j in range(mysurface.get_height()):
        color = mysurface.get_at(i,j)
        lum = get_lum(color.r,color.g,color.b)
        if(lum>maxL):
            maxL = lum
            point = (i,j)
```

This was horrendously slow, so I started doing my research. A quick check to the [pygame docs](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.get_at) showed that getting pixels 1 at a time using this method would be slow. So then I started trying using a surfarray:

```
maxL = 0
point = (0,0)
mysurface = get_cameraImg()
ar = pygame.surfarray.array3d(mysurface)
for i in range(len(ar)):
    for j in range(len(ar[i]):
        color = ar[i][j]
        lum = get_lum(color[0],color[1],color[2])
        if(lum>maxL):
            maxL = lum
            point = (i,j)
```

However, this was also too slow. A quick double check to the surfarray docs showed that pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(surface) would be faster (as no actual value is copied), but unfortunately my camera image is not 24 or 32 bit format.
So, here's my question:

In pygame, is there any quick way to read ALL pixels?

I have to be able to read every pixel, do a lum calculation on it, (maxcolor+mincolor)/2, then see if it's lum is the max lum. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the `surfarray` object is backed by numpy arrays, so your chances of getting it faster are relying on their native methods.

Take a look at this: [numpy.argmax](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#head-e2829234dedbedccc333d32ee2738c28777f2e94)

You might need to transform your 3d array to a 2d luminosity matrix first (but don't do it with nested loops! XD). Maybe you'll need some reshaping to get the planes, and then average them with simple matrix operations... Or instead of working in RGB, you could switch to other image format that is easier to work with like HSV or just grayscale.

Comment: Did not know that the surfarray was backed by numpy arrays. Looks like the sum() function will work wonders for a quick luminance calculation along with an argmax for finding the brightest point. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since the luminosity calculation is just (maxcolor+mincolor)/2, I figured best way is get the 3d array, ar, then make 2 2d arrays using ar.max(3) and ar.min(3) (to get the max/mincolor) then just lumar = (maxar + minar)/2 and finally just an argmax or max to find where the highest point in lumar is.
And yes, nested loops is probably what killed the speed. =S

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there's a way specific for Pygame, but there is a simple way to speed a lot of things up in many python programs: use Psycho, see here

http://psyco.sourceforge.net/introduction.html

Another thing that comes into my mind is: why do you have to  "find the light" by reading pixel-by-pixel? Isn't the position of the light something you already know beforehand, so you could just check the camera position relative to the light position?

Comment: The camera is fixed in place, and you control the game by moving a small LED light that's in your hand, so I don't know where the light is beforehand. The easiest way I found for finding the light is by finding the point with the highest luminence. 
As for psyco, I'll look into it but I still believe there's a simple algorithm I'm missing.

Comment: Many games ask you to set up the controler at the beginning, like in the wii, when you have to point at the center.. will that speed up the start and then you can get from there???

Comment: Even if I did have them point at the center, I would still have to process the camera image to find where the light has moved. As mentioned before, this would involve finding the point of highest luminance. Because the calculation still has to be performed, having a calibration (such as pointing at the center) will not speed up the game.