# fast way to get and set pixel color in pygame

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, pygame, pixel

I am working on a simple project using pygame and I need to get and set pixel colors.
Using `pygame.get_at(())` and `pygame.set_at(())` is VERY slow.

So I tried using PixelArray to get and set the colors manually. But this still is VERY slow

Is there a much faster way to do this?

Is it possible to make a funtion to get and set a pixel in c++ so it would be faster or is there a way in python/pygame to do it?

For example:

a c++ function that returns the pixel color at a given coordinate and another function that sets the pixel at a given coordinate to a given color.

Then I could call these functions in pygame somehow.

Thank you very much.

Comment: you want to implement a c++ function inside of a pygame?

Comment: correct (if its the fastest way to solve my problem). I need a fast way to get and set pixel colors on a pygame screen

Comment: this will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241415/import-c-function-into-python-program

Comment: have you learned c++?

Comment: yes but only basically. Never have I done any graphics with it

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a get pixel and set pixel c++ function below

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743545/pygame-quick-pixel-reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ SetPixel and GetPixel function

Part of window.h library

Set Pixel at coords with color

```
COLORREF SetPixel(
  _In_  HDC hdc,
  _In_  int X,
  _In_  int Y,
  _In_  COLORREF crColor
);
```

Return color of pixel at specified coords

```
COLORREF GetPixel(
  _In_  HDC hdc,
  _In_  int nXPos,
  _In_  int nYPos
);
```

SDL:

Get Color

```
Uint32 rawpixel = getpixel(surface, x, y);
Uint8 red, green, blue;

SDL_GetRGB(rawpixel, surface->format, &red, &green, &blue);
```

SetPixel at coords

```
void setpixel(SDL_Surface *screen, int x, int y, Uint8 r, Uint8 g, Uint8 b)
{
    Uint32 *pixmem32;
    Uint32 colour;  

    colour = SDL_MapRGB( screen->format, r, g, b );

    pixmem32 = (Uint32*) screen->pixels  + y + x;
    *pixmem32 = colour;
}
```

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145078%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Wondeful! How can this be implemented into a pygame program?

Comment: you should see the comment with the link above

Comment: I don't think this solution can be integrated with a pygame application, pygame uses SDL for rendering graphics, the functions you provide are part of the MS Windows API and are intended to be used on a Windows window, not in a pygame surface.

Comment: Sorry these two functions (window API and SDL) were the only available functions that do what the op wants